# Should I link ${catkin_LIBRARIES} to my library, or to executables?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, roscpp, linking

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here's an excerpt from my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library(my_lib <some source files>)
target_link_libraries(my_lib ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

add_executable(my_node <some source files)
target_link_libraries(my_node my_lib)
```

I found that everything works fine if I link ${catkin_LIBRARIES} to either `my_node` or `my_lib`. So is either way preferred for any reason? Is there any convention?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360932/should-i-link-$%7Bcatkin_libraries%7D-to-my-library,-or-to-executables?/) by [ItsTimmy](https://answers.ros.org/users/59000/itstimmy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The convention is that you should link all dependencies needed to a target. On Windows that is even required.

Without known what exactly is in your library / executable I can't answer the question.

If the source files of your library include headers from dependencies found with `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)` you should link `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` to your libraries. And if the source files of your executable include headers from dependencies found with `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)` (and not transitively through headers from your library) you should link `${catkin_LIBRARIES}` to your executable.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1